# Css font-family on images

Tags: image, css, fonts, font-family

I am wondering how font-family can be used for images.
I have tried different type of images with different font-family but image has no effect (As per me this should be expected).

Can some one explains me uses of font-family with images?

Thanks

Comment: One usage is when the graphic can't be loaded; then the alt text will be shown in the specified font (and color, style etc). Don't really know if there are other uses. Wait, are you talking about SVG images?

Comment: No, Images other than SVGs